# What is the meaning of delegate-handle and getByHandle?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, pdf-viewer

I ran into this construction

html part:

```
<pdf-viewer
    delegate-handle="my-pdf-container"
    url="pdfUrl"
    scale="1"
    show-toolbar="true"
    headers="{ 'x-you-know-whats-awesome': 'EVERYTHING' }"></pdf-viewer>
```

js part:

```
pdfDelegate.$getByHandle('my-pdf-container')
```

I've try to find the documentation for `delegate-handle` and `getByHandle` keywords with no success.

From syntax I can understand that is kind of id to refer from javascript code, but it still unclear for me.

Comment: where does `pdf-viewer` come from ? Please add the tag of the conscerned framework, Ionic maybe ?

Comment: I'm not sure is it angular's thin or not